# How to get share folder's file list of the remote windows server in windows platform

Tags: c++, windows

I'm developing a windows app written in C++, which needs to retrieve the file lists of the remote windows server share fold by username & passwd like:

```
BOOL GetFilesFromServerShareFolder(const CString& serversharefolderpath,
                                   const CString& username,
                                   const CString& passwd,
                                   CList<CString>& retfiles);
```

I don't how to implement it. If anybody knows some APIs or sample code or tutorial, it will be really useful.

Comment: you could have a look at the win32 api for network share management http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525393(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `WNetAddConnection2` function to connect to the shared folder.

```
NETRESOURCE nr = {0};
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
nr.lpRemoteName = serversharefolderpath;
DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, passwd, username, CONNECT_TEMPORARY);
```

Then you should be able to enumerate the files in that share with the usual FindFirstFile API.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
CString searchpath = serversharefolderpath + "\\*.*";
HANDLE findHandle = FindFirstFile(searchpath, &fd);
if (findHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  // the rest of the enumeration here
  FindClose(findHandle);
}
```

And finally cancel the connection when you're finished.

```
WNetCancelConnection2(nr.lpRemoteName, 0, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to connect to the remote resource as the desired user. You can do that using the [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413.aspx) function.

To call this function, you will fill out a [`NETRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385353.aspx) structure that describes the remote resource to which you wish to connect, and then pass a pointer to that structure to the function along with the user name and password strings, and some flags. For your purposes, you'll probably want to make sure and specify the flags `CONNECT_TEMPORARY` and `CONNECT_UPDATE_RECENT`.

Then, once you've made your connection with the desired user account, you will want to enumerate the files/folders in that share. You would do this the same way with a network share as you would with any other local folder. For example, the pair of functions [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx). There's plenty of example code available online for these functions. This is how you will fill your `CList` collection.

Finally, don't forget the [`WNetCancelConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427.aspx) function, which you'll use to disconnect from the network share once you're finished.